# Manually patching for Ghost vulnerability on legacy server

Tags: c, linux, security, centos, redhat

I have a legacy Redhat ES 3.x server (that I cannot put a later distro on due to limitations in an ancient, unsupported application) and I am trying to manually patch glibc on it for the Ghost vulnerability.

Based on the analysis by Qualys (http://www.openwall.com/lists/oss-security/2015/01/27/9), it appears that it should be easy to modify the glib source to handle the stack/heap overflow issue.  But I would like to have a few more eyes on my procedure to see if I missed something, etc.

Here is what I have done.  First I built & prepped the glib source tree from the SRPM:

```
rpm -ivh glibc-2.3.2-95.50.src.rpm
rpmbuild -bp /usr/src/redhat/SPECS/glibc.spec 
cd /usr/src/redhat/BUILD
cp -av glibc-2.3.2-200309260658 glibc-org
cd glibc-2.3.2-200309260658
```

Next, I edited nss/digits_dots.c mainly based on this paragraph from the Qalys article above:

> Lines 121-125 prepare pointers to store four (4) distinct entities in
>   buffer: host_addr, h_addr_ptrs, h_alias_ptr, and hostname. The sizeof
>   (*h_alias_ptr) -- the size of a char pointer -- is missing from the
>   computation of size_needed.

```
vi nss/digits_dots.c

I edited these two statements:
  105:  size_needed = (sizeof (*host_addr)
                   + sizeof (*h_addr_ptrs) + strlen (name) + 1);

  277:  size_needed = (sizeof (*host_addr)
                   + sizeof (*h_addr_ptrs) + strlen (name) + 1);

to this:
  105:  size_needed = (sizeof (*host_addr)
                   + sizeof (*h_addr_ptrs) + strlen (name)
                   + sizeof (*h_alias_ptr) + 1);

  277:  size_needed = (sizeof (*host_addr)
                       + sizeof (*h_addr_ptrs) + strlen (name)
                       + sizeof (*h_alias_ptr) + 1);
```

Next, I created a patch file + updated the spec file to include my patch + built binaries:

```
cd /usr/src/redhat/BUILD
diff -Npru glibc-org glibc-2.3.2-200309260658 > glibc-digit_dots-ghost.patch
cp glibc-digit_dots-ghost.patch ../SOURCES/

cd /usr/src/redhat/SPECS
vi glibc.spec
rpmbuild -ba glibc.spec
```

Lastly, I updated glibc using the new binaries (RPM):

```
cd /usr/src/redhat/RPMS/i386
rpm -Uvh --nodeps glibc-2.3.2-95.51.i386.rpm glibc-devel-2.3.2-95.51.i386.rpm glibc-profile-2.3.2-95.51.i386.rpm glibc-utils-2.3.2-95.51.i386.rpm glibc-common-2.3.2-95.51.i386.rpm glibc-headers-2.3.2-95.51.i386.rpm
```

After restarting the server, I re-ran the ghost tester (https://webshare.uchicago.edu/orgs/ITServices/itsec/Downloads/GHOST.c).

**This time I got "should not happen" instead of "vulnerable", which I guess is good.  But I had expected to get "not vulnerable"  Did I miss something, or is it just that my fix is different from the official fix in the supported distros?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been searching for similar patch for old Fedora release...
I found this Q&A over at ServerFault which is about patching older Debian Lenny:

https://serverfault.com/questions/662971/how-to-patch-cve-2015-0235-ghost-on-debian-lenny-and-squeeze

In one of the answers, they link to [official glibc patch](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=patch;h=d5dd6189d506068ed11c8bfa1e1e9bffde04decd) which the diff shows a few additional edits other than yours.  It's probably the missing  `*status = NSS_STATUS_NOTFOUND;` that is getting into the "should not happen" state.

Hope that helps!
(sorry don't have enough Rep points to upvote your question...)

Comment: Agreed.  Just look at the .patch and use that as a guide.

Comment: @jason_uruguru Thanks - I used that official glibc patch as a guide for patching my system, and it seems to have worked like a charm!

Comment: gratitude for all the info here, great learning. i'm also getting "should not happen" even though i stuck closely to the patch, other than skipping test-digits-dots.c. @Jim, was there a particular code change or config that finally made it good?

Comment: @rvh No, I just went through the full official patch and applied the same changes to my source.  What distro are you trying to patch?

Comment: @Jim, i hadn't seen the mod for getXXbyYY_r.c. once i made the change there too all went fine. i had to do one for Fedora14 and one for Fedora17. i also have an RHEL5.1 and for some reason couldn't get to the repos for that so i just pulled the glibc update from CentOS5.1 repos. worked good. there isn't a lot of info on manual patching so this post was quite helpful.